# Reorder dataframe columns while ignoring unidentified columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm thinking there's got to be a better way to do this.

I'm trying to reorder the columns in a dataframe. I have a list, `ordered.colnames`, representing the new ordering -- but *some of the columns don't exist* in `dataset`. To avoid the Error "`undefined columns selected`", I've wrapped the relevant slicing in a `try()` function.

The following method works, but is there a better way to do this?

```
> ordered.colnames[1:5]
[1] "lady_22102"         "attentions_83249"   "perseverance_17864"
[4] "cecil_84477"        "cecilia_133476"

dataset.reordered = c() 
for (i in 1:length(ordered.colnames)) {
    col = NA
    col = try(cbind(dataset[,ordered.colnames[i]]),silent=TRUE)
    if (!inherits(col,"try-error")) {
        colnames(col) = ordered.colnames[i]
        dataset.reordered = cbind(dataset.reordered, col) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can't you just do this?

```
ordered.colnames <- ordered.colnames[ordered.colnames %in% colnames(dataset)]
```